# Where is Eclipse empty shell edition?

Tags: eclipse

There're so many Eclipse editions.
I don't know well in structure of Eclipse IDE, but as I know, Eclipse is basically an empty frame for strong plug-ins. This means there should be an empty shell edition, but I couldn't find it. Most basic editions already contain many tools in it.

Where is it? And how can I obtain it?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're referring to the [Rich Client Platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform)? You'll need to download the RCP SDK to get started, then when the time comes to deploy check out the FAQ for what you need.

Comment: I think this is the minimal eclipse installation for building a platform application.

Comment: Depends what the asker actually wants to do! :)

Comment: I just wanted to test possibility of building my own development tool (IDE) :) This seems most suitable edition for my purpose...

Answer (score 3):

As mention in the recent serie "[Eclipse is…](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/wayne/2010/06/14/eclipse-is/)", Eclipse is a bit more than "an empty frame for strong plug-ins". It is also:

- [A Java IDE](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/wayne/2010/06/16/eclipse-is-a-java-ide/);
- [An IDE Framework](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/wayne/2010/06/17/eclipse-is-an-ide-platform/);
- [A Tools Framework](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/wayne/2010/06/22/eclipse-is-a-tools-platform/);
- An Application Framework;
- Runtimes;
- Open Source Projects;
- A Community;
- An Eco-system;
- A Foundation; and
- More?

You can see all the [Helios packages (distributions) here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/), the smallest one being the [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (99MB)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliosr).
You can [compare those packages](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php) in term of content.

Only the [RCP edition](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/heliosr) would allow you to build a minimal RCP application, like the one presented in this [RCP tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html):

[alt text http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/images/firstrcp70.gif](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/images/firstrcp70.gif)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are referring to the platform runtime binary, available here : http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/index.php
From eclipse download page, click "other downloads" next to eclipse classic, and then click "3.6" on the next page.

Comment: Yes, this is the minimal version of eclipse. It is somewhat hidden in ["Eclipse Project Downloads"](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/).