# How to launch minimal eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

This my seem a little odd but I want to start eclipse (v3.5) in the most minimal version possible. Pherhaps just the core and the ui component without anything else. I'm new to eclipse Plugin Development so I don't really know if this is possible at all?

I googled this topic but there seems to be no useful info out there. Perhaps someone can help me...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. On this [webpage](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html) in Section 3 "Create your first RCP application". There a minimal application based on the Extensions

- org.eclipse.core.runtime.apllications
- org.eclipse.ui.perspectives

is created.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126970/where-is-eclipse-empty-shell-edition/3127055#3127055

Comment: Don't be afraid to mark your answer as correct if you're reasonably confident there isn't a more suitable solution out there.